# Remove category name from product page

Tags: category, title

please advise.
I have 4-5 types of categories: by type, by season, by purpose, recommended, etc.
Some products are located in few categories at the same time, for example masala tea can be in "black tea" category, in "loose leaf tea" category and in "arabic flavours" at the same time. When i go to product card itself it shows at the top category name and most of the time the one which is not related to the category i am in at the moment. Ho can i remove category title from product card page at all in using admin access only?

Comment: Can you please share screenshot and highlight in that, what do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Find the template file and override it. 
Method 2: Via CSS hide the element